# How to make sure any new Component which includes a DLL added in .ISM project , always get the last sequence number in File Table upon generating MSI

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

How to make sure any new Component which includes a DLL added in .ISM project , always get the last sequence number in File Table upon generating MSI from the ism source.

As currently in my project when I add a Component the File in Component post build getting the sequence number in between other existing files in File Table of MSI thus increasing the sequence number other existing file's which are not updated or change in File table.

Comment: Can we ask what you need this for? Some sort of automation?

Comment: this coz when we create patch the old existing binaries are also coming as diff due to change in File sequence number ,

Comment: Patching is very difficult with Installshield and I am not able to test it now. I have made patches with Wise and WiX that worked OK, but I never had much luck with InstallShield. The product was a bit complicated, and patching is already difficult - plus some InstallShield peculiarities like you describe. Did you try modifying tables with the Direct Editor view or with Orca? You could try the modify from both the ISM and in the compiled MSI? Is this a requirement though? To have the same sequence number? I am not sure it is.

Comment: Not much control from Direct Editor , it get's compiled and placed in MSI which is output that we don't wanted to modify manually . But should be Ok though no luck how Sequence number get's change for existing one's . We are making sure the diff files all are available in msp via pcp configuration , this way we solving the issue for now